# How do we prove $\left(1 + \frac 1 {\sin\theta}\right)(\sin\theta-\sin^2\theta)=\cos^2\theta$?

Tags: trigonometry

Please show me the steps to completing this:

$$\left(1 + \frac 1 {\sin\theta}\right)(\sin\theta-\sin^2\theta) = \cos^2\theta.$$

Thanks.

Edit: Understood, thanks for the help.

Comment: Just multiply out all the terms. You'll be left with $1-\sin^2\theta$ which is equal to the answer you seek to prove.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this equation is _not_ correct - the LHS is undefined where $\sin\theta=0$ (i.e., for all values $\theta=n\pi$). It has a valid limit whose value is equal to $\cos^2\theta$ at those values and is the same everywhere else, but it's still defined over a different set than the RHS as written.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)(a-a^2)=
\frac{a+1}{a}a(1-a)=(a+1)(1-a)=1-a^2
$$

Answer (score 4):

$$
(1+\frac{1}{\sin(\theta)})(\sin(\theta)-\sin^{2}(\theta))\\
=\sin(\theta)+1-\sin^{2}(\theta)-\sin(\theta)=\cos^{2}(\theta).
$$